# count and group by postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my table:

```
  project_id | task_id | foo | bar | job_id |
  -----------+---------+-----+-----+--------+
      1           12      x     y       13
      1           12      x     z       14
      1           12      a     b       15
      1         1210      x     y     1211
      1         1210      z     v     1212 
      1         1220     aa    bb     1221
```

I trying to write a query where `group by` by `task_id` and count `job_id` per `task_id`

So I expect something like that:

```
project_id | task_id | foo | bar | job_id | countJobsperTask |
-----------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------------+
    1             12      x    y      13          3
    1             12      x    z      14          3        
    1             12      a    b      15          3
    2             1210    x    y      1211        2
    2             1210    z    v      1212        2
    3             1220    aa   bb     1221        1
```

My not very successful query :

```
select 
    project_id, task_id, foo, bar, job_id, 
    count(job_id) as "countJobsperTask" 
from
    project 
group by 
    project_id, task_id, job_id
```

Comment: Based on your test data, each of your groups contains exactly one row, as specified by your `GROUP BY` terms.  If you want to select the original rows (ungrouped), but calculate an aggregate `OVER` some similar rows, you can use window functions, as shown by @Pooya's answer.  There are also several ways to use `GROUP BY` in a separate expression and then refer to that in your select list.  There is a question about how you want to count job_id (distinct or not).  That would need to be specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why `project_id` is different between your sample data and expected data, but this query maybe helps you:

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ba6ba5b1e574c6de0e06fb9810cf0884)

```sql
select 
  project_id, 
  task_id, 
  foo, 
  bar, 
  job_id, 
  count(job_id) over (partition by project_id, task_id)
from project
```

Comment: you understood correctly there are still different projects